# infinite loop issue when I try to get the common divisor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, infinite

I am trying to get the closest common divisor of some numbers but, for some reason, the code gets into an infinite loop and idk why. For example, let's say that i have the numbers 2, 3 and 4. In this case, the closest common divisor is 12 (12 % 2 = 0, 12 % 3 = 0, 12 % 4 = 0). Here is my code:

```
function sumFracts(l) {
  let isDivis = false;
  let divisor = 1;
  while (!isDivis) {
    divisor++;
    isDivis = true;
    l.map((v, i) => {
      v % divisor !== 0 ? isDivis = false : isDivis;
    });
  }
  return divisor
}
```

Where l = [2, 3, 4] ;

Please give me some explication about what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: If you're not using the result, you should use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: That's the Least Common Multiple, not the common divisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`12` is the Least Common Multiple of `2, 3, 4`, not a divisor.

You have your modulus backwards. In your text you show `12 % 2 == 0`, which is correct, but the function is testing `2 % 12 !== 0`.

You can also use the `every()` method instead of `map()`.

```js
function lcm(l) {
  let product = l.reduce((acc, cur) => acc * cur, 1);
  for (let multiple = 1; multiple <= product; multiple++) {
    if (l.every(v => multiple % v == 0)) {
      return multiple;
    }
  }
}

console.log(lcm([2, 3, 4]));
console.log(lcm([5, 7, 11, 13]));
```

You can find more efficient methods of calculating LCM in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Computing_the_least_common_multiple)

Comment: Thanks! This one works, sorry for the wrong title description.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumFracts(l) {
    let isDivis = false;
    let divisor = 1;
    while (isDivis===false) {
        divisor++;         
        isDivis = l.every(el=>((divisor % el) == 0));                  
    }
    return divisor
}

console.log(sumFracts([2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: What's the `if (divisor > 20)` for? You're never using it.

Comment: yes, i forget remove this, it;s help not to go to infinite loop